# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on non-object. mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the below code to check if a row exists then do something. However, I am getting

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

I have found out that if I put `$check->get_result();` before  `$check->store_result();` This error goes away but when I do that and echo `$check->num_rows;` I get empty result even though I have one row in the table. What am I doing wrong?

`var_dump($check_result);` gives me the below

```
0bject(mysqli_result)#6 (5) { 
    ["current_field"]=> int(0) 
    ["field_count"]=> int(25) 
    ["lengths"]=> NULL 
    ["num_rows"]=> int(1) 
    ["type"]=> int(0) 
}
```

here is the query...

```
$material = '';

$check_added = $mysqli->prepare("select * from table where material = ? order by id desc limit 1");
$check_added->bind_param('s', $material);
$check_added->execute();
$check_result = $check_added->get_result();
$check_added->store_result();
echo $check_added->num_rows;
if($check_added->num_rows < 1)
{
    //Do something
}
else
{       
    while($checkrow = $check_result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $checkrow['title'];
    }
```

Comment: `var_dump($check_result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$check_added is a mysqli prepared statement object that you're treating like a result set, have you treid $check_result->num_rows?

Comment: oh I had to do `$check_result->num_rows;` thanks now it works.

Comment: Cool. Stuff like that happens all the time